# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined on image?

Tags: node.js

I create a POST Endpoint to Upload Image to AWS S3 but i got an error when i tried to use to replace information of image information except base64 data

```
const imageAWS = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res) => {
  const { image } = req.body
  // Prepare the image
  const base64Data = new Buffer.from(
    image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ''),
    'base64'
  )

  const type = image.split(';')[0].split('/')[1]

  // Image params
  const params = {
    Bucket: '',
    Key: `S{nanoid()}.${type}`,
    Body: base64Data,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: `image/${type}`,
  }

  // Upload to S3
  S3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler('Upload Failed', 400))
    }
    // log
    console.log(data)
  })

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
  })
})
```

Error Message Postman

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 500,
        "message": "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"
    },
    "message": "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"
}
```

Comment: `req.body` exists, but `req.body.image` does not. Have you had a look at what the request actually returns?

Comment: @LukeBriggs yes i create image key using form-data on postman. when i return req.body `"----------------------------221091136581883415727306\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"sa.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg"`

Comment: if `req.body` is just that string, strings don't have a property called `image` so attempting to get `aString.image` will be undefined. What are you expecting `const { image } = req.body` to do?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that the `req.body` isn't an object, so the property `image` from `const { image } = req.body` is undefined.

You could use following method to convert `req.body` into an object if it is JSON:
`const { image } = JSON.parse(req.body)`